# Prove the orthogonal projections of $S$ form a tangent quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

> Diagonals of the cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ are intersecting each other at the point $S$. Orthogonal projections of $S$ on the edges of the quadrilateral lie on those edges respectively. Prove those projections are vertices of a tangent quadrilateral.

My attempt:
$$\measuredangle CAB=\measuredangle CDB\;\land\;\measuredangle BSA=\measuredangle DSC\;\implies\;\Delta ABS{\sim}\Delta CDS$$
Analogously:$$\Delta DAS{\sim}\Delta BCS$$
Let $E,F,G,H$ be the orthogonal projections on the edges $\overline{AB},\overline{BC},\overline{CD},\overline{DA}$ of $ABCD$ respectively.

The given right-triangles:
$$\Delta HAS,\Delta SAE, \Delta BSE,\ldots$$

I wanted to use the mentioned above to show:
$$|EF|+|GH|=|FG|+|HE|,$$
but it went unsuccessfully.

So far, I've learned:

> The center of the incircle of a tangent quadrilateral is the intersection point of the four angle-bisectors.

While drawing the polygons and circles in GeoGebra, I saw the diagonals of $ABCD$ and the four angle-bisectors of $EFGH$ intersect each other at $S$, so $S$ is the center of the incircle of $EFGH$.

However, I haven't managed to prove it.
Picture (Where I also drew a right-triangle $\Delta RQU$ because I thought I could use:$\measuredangle QSR=2\measuredangle QUS$):
[image]

May I ask for advice on solving this task? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\measuredangle LFS=\measuredangle LBS=\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle ACD=\measuredangle SFG,$$ which says that $FS$ is a bisector of $\angle LFG.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you for responding! I don't have any point $L$ in my picture, so I got confused.

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya In your picture $L$ is a projection of $S$ on $AB$.

Comment: Oh, my bad, $E$ is blurry.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can end it.