# The diagonals of cyclic $ABCD$ meet at $P$, and $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are feet of perpendiculars from $P$ to the sides. Show $WX+YZ=XY+WZ$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $ABCD$ be a cyclic quadrilateral whose diagonals meet at $P$. Let $W$, $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be the feet of $P$ onto $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, and $DA$ respectively. Show that $WX+YZ=XY+WZ$

I tried a lot but in vain. I literally have no idea how to begin and approach the problem. Probably, properties of circles and triangles will be used but I don't know from which to start with.
Please help.

Comment: I've no idea either but that's cool if it's true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the orthogonal projections of $S$ form a tangent quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583347/prove-the-orthogonal-projections-of-s-form-a-tangent-quadrilateral)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you "literally have no idea" about a problem, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, say something about the topic(s) covered in the chapter. If it's a contest problem or online challenge, say something about the intended audience (grade level, etc). This information can help answerers tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time explaining things you understand or using techniques beyond the intended skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you..)

Comment: @ Blue. I accept that I should have elaborated that problem. But it is not my homework problem. It is from my self-study material which i am using to prepare for an exam (JEE). Thanks for making me aware on how to write a question more elaborately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir8qx.png)

As, $AZPW$, $PWBX$, $XPYC$, and $YPZD$ all are cyclic,
$\measuredangle PAZ = \measuredangle  PWZ = \measuredangle  PWX = \measuredangle PBX$.

Hence, $P$ lies on the angle bisector of the $\angle XWZ$.
Similarly, we can prove $P$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle WXY, \angle ZYX, \angle YXW$.

Hence, $P$ is the incenter of $WXYZ$.

From Pitot's Theorem, we can conclude $WX + YZ = WZ + XY$. **QED**

> This is my first answer in Math-StackExchange. Please forgive my technical mistakes :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: I'm glad that the answer helped you :)